# WinKill() source code

Tags: c++, autoit

Can somebody share source code of [`WinKill()` from AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinKill.htm)?

I want to know how it works with messages (yes/no/cancel) to be sure it's handled properly. I want to use it to clean desktop from unexpected pop-up windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see below in the source code taken from the latest open source release of AutoIt (when it used to be open-source) and available [here](https://github.com/ellysh/au3src/blob/35517393091e7d97052d20ccdee8d9d6db36276f/src/script_win.cpp#L701), the function sends WM_CLOSE message to the window. If the window doesn't get closed on 500ms, then it kills the process that created the window.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WinKill()
// Closes a window - uses more force than WinClose
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

AUT_RESULT AutoIt_Script::F_WinKill(VectorVariant &vParams, Variant &vResult)
{
    Win_WindowSearchInit(vParams);

    if (Win_WindowSearch() == false)
        return AUT_OK;                          // Required window not found

    Util_WinKill(m_WindowSearchHWND);
    Util_Sleep(m_nWinWaitDelay);                // Briefly pause before continuing

    return AUT_OK;

} // WinKill()

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Util_WinKill()
//
// Closes a window with extreme predjudice
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void Util_WinKill(HWND hWnd)
{
    DWORD      dwResult;

    LRESULT lResult = SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, &dwResult);   // wait 500ms

    if( !lResult )
    {
        // Use more force - Mwuahaha

        // Get the ProcessId for this window.
        DWORD   pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &pid );

        // Open the process with all access.
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

        // Terminate the process.
        TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

} // Util_WinKill()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not an open source function. You can not know the source. However it is not complicated to understand. It is a simple function with a lot of If...then... calls to check the standards and then a simple kill of the window. Very similar to what you would do with an cmd command.

AutoIt has native and standard functions. Native ones are open source and you can find them in your AutoIt installed directory in the Include folder.
Standard ones on the other way are not open source. They are written in C++.